# My Tata Photon Whiz modem is detected as storage device instead of a modem

Tags: modem

My computers's processor is Pentium 4. Speed 3 GH RAM 512 MB
My computer's OS is Ubuntu 11.10

My modem is Tata Photon Whiz which works as a modem in addition to a storage deice in Wndows XP; but whenever I connect it in Ubuntu 11.10, it is detected only as a storage device in stead of a modem. Please help me as I am very much  desperate to use internet in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you got your answer, but I got a couple of these devices (was some time ago, do not remember makes/models) working OK in 11.10 and 12.04 via a script called Sakis3G.

Sakis3G knows how to switch dongles' modes (mass storeage to modem).

You can read about and get it [here](http://www.sakis3g.org/).

It takes care of most dongles by itself (no config needed), has a nice UI and... works. You could/should be asked for your password as some work is done as **root** in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Many such devices have both and use the storage part to hold Windows drivers for the modem part.  The device takes a command to switch between modes.  The usb-modeswitch package has the program and the database of commands to use for switching known devices.  Whether or not your particular device is supported I couldn't say.  Install usb-modeswitch if it's not already, and then open a terminal and type man usb-modeswitch for instructions on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Tata Photon modems are both USB Modems as well as microSD readers;

- Check whether there is any microSD card inserted into the modem.
- Still If you see the modem as storage device, unmount that drive.